# Android notification intent creates new instance instead of opening existing instance

Tags: java, android

If I click my notification while the app is minimized it opens the app and the UI is reset. I would like the notification to open the existing instance. I've been trying to make it use the existing instance.

This is my notification code:

```
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("Tuned in to " + radiostation);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RadioChooser.class);

            resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(RadioChooser.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            getApplicationContext(), 0,
                            resultIntent, 0
                    );
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".RadioChooser"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MusicPlayer" />
</application>
```

Comment: You did not specify any problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: @Shlublu I'm sorry. It opens a new instance and I want it to open the minimized instance of the app so the interface isn't reset.

Comment: Ok, I see. I cannot answer this one, but if you update your question you'll have more chances to see it answered.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I've updated my title with the problem :).

Comment: `it opens a new instance` that's what `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` do.

Comment: @njzk2 Removing that flag fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, nomatter how you try to do this, the Activity will most likely be restarted if it has been minimized(sometimes it is not though). You need to prepare for it to ALWAYS be restarted. The way to go about this is, in our `onSaveInstanceState()` method, store all of the UI related variables. Then, either in `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`, re-initialize those variables and build your UI back up from their value. So, if you use fragments to display different pages of your app, when the main activity is stopped and `onSaveInstance()` is called, store the name or number or some identifier of which fragment it was in the Bundle object that `onSaveInstance()` passes. When the activity is recreated, your code should take those variables from the bundle passed in `onCreate()`, and use them to display the correct fragment, with the correct information.